# Does Android Studio Linter Offer An Option to look for default XML layout values?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, lint

1.) Is there any reason to have a default value inside an android xml layout?

Ex.) The TextView below has included a default value of 
    `android:visibility="visible"`

```
`<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"/>`
```

Conjecture: Because this is a default value, it has no effect, and therefore is an unnecessary line of code in the XML file. Is that line of thinking correct?

2.) If there is no reason for default values to exist in Android xml files, is there a lint plugin available to point out default value code lines in android XML files?

It is my thought that a large number of code lines in XML files are default values, serving no purpose. What can we do to reduce these lines of code?

Comment: I don't know how they check for mandatory attributes (android:layout_width, android:layout_height for example) but if you find that out, perhaps you can invert the approach to find/mark non-mandatory attributes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can create a style with your default values and use it.
For example:

```
<style name="DefaultTextViewStyle">
    <item name="android:visibility">visible</item>
</style>
```

to use this:

```
<TextView
   style="@style/DefaultTextViewStyle" />
```

Comment: This addresses the first question, that there is sometimes a need for android:visibility = "visible", but I wish there was a linter to help me find default values nonetheless since I typically don't use styles.

Answer (score 1):

I had some hope that the Lint inspection `Redundant default value attribute assignment` for xml, run via Android Studio might have done what you're asking.  You can run it as specified under the [Manually Run Inspections](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint#manuallyRunInspections) part of the Android docs.  i.e.Android Studio -> Analyze -> Run Inspection by name -> enter "Redundant default value attribute assignment", then select the scope for the Lint check.
[image]
[image]

Sadly though, it doesn't pick up the case you mention above.  I'm just wondering if there's something I've missed, or if this isn't intended for Android xml in some way?